# MSIE11, popup window using window.close() erases a variable just set

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, popupwindow

SUMMARY:
In MSIE 11, in a popup window when I fill a certain field with data it stays filled, or not, depending on if the popup window has window.close() called on it.  Can't repeat with other browsers.

DETAILS: 
I have a popup web page (a JSP page, if it matters to someone) I use to fill existing fields in a web form.  I added a new field and it is filling OK -- sometimes.

Here is the pertinent section of the page, cleaned up for presentation.  My actual page doesn't hard-code emails in the Javascript object.

```
function fillForm() {

    var parentWindowOrder = window.opener.salesOrder;
    var formData = parentWindowOrder.workingData;

    [snip]
    var xferEmails = {"emails":["jerome@myserver.com","jerome2@otherserver.com"]};
    formData.user_emails = xferEmails.emails;
    [snip]
}

window.close();  // HERE IS THE TOGGLE OF MY PROBLEM
```

In MSIE, if window.close() is disabled (commented out) then everything works OK.  Elsewhere in the page the formData.user_emails can be referenced OK.  Of course, the popup page still exists and must be manually closed.  When using the console the query yields:

```
>formData.user_emails
["jerome@myserver.com","jerome2@otherserver.com"]
```

In MSIE, if window.close() is executed in the popup then the popup closes, of course. However, the values stored aren't preserved.  When in the popup window itself, either before or after calling window.close(), the field is set and stays set.  But after that the values are gone:

```
>formData.user_emails
{}
```

In other browsers I get the success condition.

Normally you'd say "You're changing the value elsewhere in your code";  however, I've already swept through my code looking for other references.  Here, shown above, is the only place it gets set in my scenario.

In my practice other fills of variables through JSON-like syntax (xferEmails) works OK, even in MSIE.  Not this particular one.  What with window.close() could influence this?

Thanks for replies,
Jerome.

Comment: `formData.user_emails` is just a reference to `xferEmails`, the referred object is gone when you close the window. Set the value literally to `formData.user_emails`, and create a copy to `xferEmails` if you'll need it before closing.

Answer (score 0):

`formData` is initialized in the popup opened and within the scope of `fillForm` function. This is assigned to `salesOrder` variable of parent window. Did you re-initialize `formData` with `salesOrder` in parent window? If you didn't then it should be accessible via `salesOrder`.